# Saving UIImage With No Quality Loss

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uiimage

My app takes screenshot of entire web pages. When it saves to Photo Album, the image quality suffers a bit and text on still image is blurry and hard to read. I found this solution which promises to have a better quality when saving to Photo Album, but it still appears to not be perfectly acceptable. Is there a better way than this to save UIImage to Photo Album with very minimal quality loss? Thanks.

```
UIImage* img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:screenshotImage.CGImage];
NSData* imdata =  UIImagePNGRepresentation ( img );
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithData:imdata]; // wrap UIImage around PNG representation

UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, @selector(image:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:), nil);
```

Comment: Did you check `img` and `image` quality (probably displaying at image view) ?

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1703/_index.html

Comment: where do you lose the quality? please, present some screenshot how you mean _lose quality_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to looking at the image quality settings, you need to be aware of which image formats are best for storing different types of images.

I prefer JPG for real world images such as those taken with a camera.  JPEG does a better job of retaining high image quality while achieving good compression.

If you are taking a screenshot where a lot of the parts of the image are the same color (like this web page or your programming editor), then I prefer to use PNG.  PNG will save the image without creating a lot of the dirty artifacts that often appear in JPEG but will still achieve good compression ratio for these types of images.

The reasons for the above have to do with the compression algorithms each use (JPEG is FFT; PNG is DEFLATE).  Try changing the image type as well as the quality settings and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Thank you. Let me do some investigation and come back with results.

Comment: UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(webView.scrollView.contentSize, NO, 0); gave me very satisfying results.